# Fragment's getView() returning null in a OnClickListener callback

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-support-library

I'm using the support library and I have a Fragment (I'll call "MyFragment") implementing a method invoked by one of the Fragment's View during an OnClick event. The OnClickListener is set in the
OnActivityCreate method like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle inState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(inState);

    ViewGroup base = (ViewGroup) getView();
    TextView tv = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.monografiat);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showStuff(); // MyFragment:150
        }
    });
}
```

where showStuff() triggers a change in the Fragment's View, something as simple as updating the visibility of an item:

```
private void showStuff() {  //MyFragment:95
    ViewGroup base = (ViewGroup) getView();
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) base.findViewById(R.id.someview); // MyFragment:97
    ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Everything works fine on my tests, and the same can be said about most of my users, however I have received today a single ANR report from Google Play developer's console, stating that the app crashed for a user with a NullPointerException on the line:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) base.findViewById(R.id.someview);
```

which means that:

```
ViewGroup base = (ViewGroup) getView();
```

returned null. This is the report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mypackage.MyFragment.showStuff(MyFragment.java:97)
    at mypackage.MyFragment.access$0(MyFragment.java:95)
    at mypackage.MyFragment$2.onClick(MyFragment.java:150)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have fixed the problem (or so I think, since I don't have a method of reproduction...) by just surrounding the offending lines with a:

```
if(base != null) {
}
```

my best guess is that the callback has been scheduled **after** onDestroyView has been called on MyFragment, thus resulting in getView() returning null.

Still, I'm quite puzzled by this bug, so I'd like your insights on the matter:

1. assuming that my hypotesys is correct, is it normal for a OnClick callback to be executed when no layout is present, or can I regard this behavior as a bug (honestly: the view was obviously there when I clicked it, why should it die on me)?
2. Is this problem related to the fact that I'm using the support library (last version, 13 May 2013)?
3. If it's not a bug and I'm missing something, could you please point me to the relevant documentation?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Any reason you're using `ViewGroup` in place of just `View`? Can you also check if `R.id.someview` is defined in the view that `getView()` returns?

Comment: Not in this particular occasion, however I know that the layout is a subclass of ViewGroup (and Java would throw a ClassCastException otherwise). As for the R.id.someview, if the corresponding view would not be found, the exception would have been thrown on line 98 (instead that on 97)

Comment: You're right, I missed that completely.

Comment: nop: thank you anyway

Comment: The `onActivityCreated()` callback is for the `MyFragment` right? Also, the `base` variable used in the `onActivityCreated()` is ...?

Comment: oops... my bad, in my effort for simplification I skipped that line. I confirm that the onActivityCreated is for the file MyFragment (all code belong to that class). Thank you for the remark!

Comment: Have similar crashreport, onClick chain call crashed because fragment getView == null... Very confusing how this might have happened...

Comment: Any reason you're not initiating that `l1` variable once in your onCreateView or something? 

One other thing, if `showStuff` is a `private` member of your Fragment, you shouldn't even need to call `getView` to get a `base` variable.

Comment: there was no particular reason to initialize ll in `onCreateView` (performance *and* memory-wise), and I prefer (for DRY/tidiness-related reason) to avoid cached variables in the instance if they are easy to compute and saving them is not critical (btw the code I wrote run just great on a low-end GT5500). As for the second question, I'm sorry but I don't  think I have understood it: as far as I know `getView` is the right method to get the base view of a fragment (if any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up until Gingerbread there was a bug in the `View` click mechanism in that the callback for performing the click was not removed from the message queue when the `View` was detached from the `Window`. This has been fixed in ICS (or possibly in Honeycomb). Therefore if you're supporting Gingerbread or below, and your click listeners access other references that are removed when the `View`s are detached, then you should make sure to remove your click listeners upon detachment as well.

Note that this applies to all kinds of click listeners, not just `OnClickListener`. However it doesn't apply to long click listeners, as their callbacks were removed properly from the beginning.

Comment: This matches the problem perfectly (pity I didn't found about this when I was developing the app in question... :| ): can you please provide some authoritative source for this problem? Then I'll mark your answer as the solution. Thank you

Comment: I am not aware of any old bug report on this to reference, but the most authoritative source is the [_source_](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/view/View.java/?v=diff&id2=2.3.7_r1#9791) ;)

Comment: I see: from a cursory look, I would say the problem is at line 5843 (a missing "removeTapCallback") when the window loses it's focus. Great job, really! Thank you!

Comment: Actually the real fix is at line #9796 with the inclusion of the `removePerformClickCallback()` among the other callback removals in the `onDetachedFromWindow()` callback. I linked to that portion of the diff, but it only jumps to the section when the page is fully loaded. And you're welcome - even if you set me back in my quest for the Treasure Hunter hat via the Unsung Hero badge by upvoting and accepting my answer :)